# An intitutive solution to problems relating to closed sets in topology

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

The question given in my homework problem is,

Let $ \{A_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in \Lambda} $ be a family of closed subsets in an arbitary topological space $X$ . Assume that for each $x$ there exists an open subset of $G_{x}$ of $X$ containing $x$ such that $ \{ \alpha \in \Lambda : G_{x} \cap A_{\alpha} \neq \emptyset \} $ is a finite set.
Prove that $ \cup A_{\alpha} $ is a closed set.

Another Question is that prove in a subspace topology induced by a set $Y$  a set $A$ in $Y$ is closed iff $A=A_{2}\cup{Y}$ where $A_{2}$ is a closed set in the original topology $X$

One of my friend showed me a proof for the first problem, it came by expanding it into open sets and proof by contradiction, however i would like to know a beautiful trick or insight rather than brute forcing the way. 
The second question is a standard problem in books like Munkres but the soluton again seemed very artifical and non intitutive to me, I would appreciate it if someone gave me insights about these two questions in particular and how to deal with proving some sets are closed. Since the only way i can think of is to prove that its complement is open which leads to very brute force type solutions

Comment: In a space with a countable base of neighborhoods you can prove a set is closed by using sequences. Such proofs can often be extended to general topological spaces using nets, which are explained in a short chapter in Munkres topology. Sometimes nets can make certain argument simpler or more intuitive, since they extended your Euclidean intuition about closedness and convergence of sequences.

For the second question, do you mean $A = A_2 \cap Y$?

About the first question, I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Can't I just take $G_x$ to be the entire space? What exactly is your condition?

Comment: "$X$ containing $X$"?

Comment: "an open subset $G_x$ of $X$ containing $x$", one upper case $X$ for the space, one lower case $x$ for the point. And you've left out the condition. It's that the set $\{ \alpha \in \Lambda : G_x \cap A_\alpha \neq \varnothing\}$ **is finite**. The term is that the family $\{A_\alpha : \alpha \in \Lambda\}$ is _locally finite_.

Comment: Made corrections, there were a few typos as graciously pointed out by David Fischer

Comment: Is $A=A_2∪Y$ or $A=A_2\cap Y$? Since $A\subset Y$, $A=A_2∪Y$ is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to prove the complement of $\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Lambda } A_{\alpha}$ is open by finding an open set for each point $x$ not in $\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Lambda } A_{\alpha}$.

Let $x\notin \bigcup_{\alpha\in\Lambda } A_{\alpha}$, and $G_x$ be an open set that $x\in G_x$. Let $A_1,\cdots,A_n$ be finite number of $A_{\alpha}$ that $G_x\cap A_n\ne \varnothing$.

Now let $G_x'=G_x-\bigcup_{i\leqslant n}A_i$. So $G_x'\ne\varnothing$ for if $G_x'=\varnothing$, then 
$$
x\in G_x\subset \bigcup_{i\leqslant n}A_i\subset \bigcup_{\alpha\in\Lambda } A_{\alpha}
$$
which is contradiction. Also since
$$
G_x'=G_x-\bigcup_{i\leqslant n}A_i=G_x\cap\left(\bigcup_{i\leqslant n}A_i\right)^c
$$
$G_x'$ is open for $\bigcup_{i\leqslant n}A_i$ is closed and $G_x$ is open.

Note that $G_x'\cap A_i=\varnothing$ for $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$. So 
$$
G_x'\cap \bigcup_{\alpha\in\Lambda } A_{\alpha}=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Lambda } (G_x'\cap A_{\alpha})=\bigcup_{i\leqslant n}(G_x'\cap A_i)=\varnothing
$$
Thus for any $x\notin \bigcup_{\alpha\in\Lambda } A_{\alpha}$, there is an open set $G_x',\:x\in G_x'$ such that $G_x'\subset \left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Lambda } A_{\alpha}\right)^c$, which means $\left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Lambda } A_{\alpha}\right)^c$ is open or $\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Lambda } A_{\alpha}$ is closed. That proves the 1st question.

Answer (score 0):

I had actually read the question wrong, now i have a beautiful solution
A set $\cup A_{\alpha}\ ,  \alpha \in \Lambda $ is closed iff $\cup A_{\alpha} =\bar{\cup A_{\alpha} } \ ,  \alpha \in \Lambda $ .
Now let $x \in \bar{\cup A_{\alpha}} $ and $ x \not \in  \cup A_{\alpha} $

Now consider the set $G_{x} $ as given in the question, let $ A_{i} \ 1\leq i\leq n$ be the sets with which it has a nonzero intersection,
Now consider the set $B = G_{x}\cap  A_{i}^{c} \ 1\leq i\leq n $ . Clearly $x \in B$ and $B$ is open, now it can be obviously seen $ B \cap A_{\alpha} = \phi \ ,  \alpha \in \Lambda$. Hence getting a contradiction that $x$ is a limit point of the set

Comment: I am sorry it should be $A_{i}^{c}$

Comment: In this case, $B$ must be disjoint with any $A_i$ that $G_x\cap A_i\ne \varnothing$. So $B=\bigcap(G_x\cap A_i^c)=G_x\cap(\bigcap A_i^c)=G_x\cap\left(\bigcup_{i\leqslant n}A_i\right)^c$, which is exactly what I have in the proof. So do not count on silver bullet or easy path. Hard proof is inevitable and you have to face it.

Comment: You are right the there is no easy way, the trick is to construct an open set since there are only finite intersections, however i dont like to convert closed sets to open sets needlessly. Your proof is of the same hardness its just that mine is more intutitvely clear to me.